# How to check total and remaining size of amazon s3 bucket using spring application?

Tags: java, spring, amazon-s3

I'm working on a spring application.
I need to check the total and current size of my amazon s3 bucket.
How can I check it in a spring application?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no limit on the amount of data and number of objects you can store in an S3 bucket, you can't check total and remaining size of a bucket. The size limit for objects in a bucket is 5TB.

One way to get the current size of a bucket is using [getSize()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/S3ObjectSummary.html#getSize--) to get the size of an object and iterate over all the objects in your bucket.

Comment: Does this 5TB mean, the total size of a bucket?

Comment: 5 TB for an object, like image, music, video, etc. that you upload to a bucket

Comment: So for every bucket in S3, the amount of data that can be stored is unlimited. Right?

Comment: Yes, according to this source https://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/#:~:text=The%20total%20volume%20of%20data,single%20PUT%20is%205%20gigabytes.